# ResourceLeak turned on paranoid level got some netty leak stack traces

Tags: java, netty, nio

When running the new 4.1.0.Alpha1 netty with my version HTTP server with ResourceLeak level set to "paranoid" and stress testing with Jmeter, I found there are some potential leaks ALL happening in netty codes - none of my HTTP server codes.
Not sure where are the leaks in the following netty stack traces:

```
#4:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.release(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:721)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.release(DefaultHttpContent.java:84)
    io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:93)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:91)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:856)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:494)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:824)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
#3:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.slice(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:51)
    io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponent0(CompositeByteBuf.java:172)
    io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponent(CompositeByteBuf.java:111)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:205)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:52)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:856)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:494)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:824)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
#2:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.order(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:41)
    io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponent0(CompositeByteBuf.java:172)
    io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.addComponent(CompositeByteBuf.java:111)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:205)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:52)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:856)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:494)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:824)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
#1:
    io.netty.buffer.AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.retain(AdvancedLeakAwareByteBuf.java:693)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.retain(DefaultHttpContent.java:60)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:204)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectAggregator.decode(HttpObjectAggregator.java:52)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:89)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:856)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:494)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:824)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Created at:
    io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:250)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:155)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:146)
    io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:83)
    io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.readBytes(ByteBufUtil.java:324)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:343)
    io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.decode(HttpClientCodec.java:140)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:362)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:141)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:155)
    io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.invokeChannelReadNow(ChannelHandlerInvokerUtil.java:83)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.invokeChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerInvoker.java:153)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelHandlerContext.java:186)
    io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:856)
    io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:116)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:494)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:461)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:378)
    io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:350)
    io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:824)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

My pipelines are typical HTTP server stacks.

```
if (isHttps) {
    final SSLEngine engine = SslContextFactory.getServerContext().createSSLEngine();
    engine.setUseClientMode(false);
    pipeline.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
}

pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpServerCodec( , , );
pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(nnnnnnn));
pipeline.addLast("compression", new HttpContentCompressor());
pipeline.addLast("idleAware", new IdleStateHandler(timeout, timeout, 0));

// My Handler ...
```

Comment: what's the question here?

Comment: Could you upgrade to the latest snapshot of 4.1.0.Alpha1 and post the leak report?  Upgrade should be as simple as recompilation.  4.1 gives us more hint.

Comment: Now stack traces replaced with the netty-4.1.0.Alpha1 (branch 4.1).

Comment: @eis The question is that why the leak happened the netty internal calls, not some calls in my own handler to process content()?

Comment: Somehow the new leak detector did not give us meaningful information.  I wanna reproduce this by myself.  Would you mind if I ask you to file an issue and provide a standalone example that reproduces the problem? Maybe a small modification of Snoop server example would do.